# How to change font without breaking Unicode glyph mapping?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I am using Emacs 24.5 (stock Debian jessie) with a UHD display.  I am over 50 and I need a large font.  I have found a font that works well, but when I set the font using

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Droid Sans Mono" :height 130)
```

it breaks the rendering of Unicode character U+2099 (Latin subscript small letter N).  The glyph renders not as a subscript n but as a superscript theta.

I have verified with `emacs -q` that the stock distribution renders the subscript small N correctly with the default font, and that the single command above is enough to break the small N.  My other unicode subscripts, Greek letters, and math symbols seem to render correctly.

How can I change the main font without breaking the mapping of the subscript small N?

Comment: Do you have `(set-language-environment "UTF-8")`  and 
`(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)` in your init.el? Are these Unicode characters available within Droid Sans Mono, i.e., are they displayed correctly with any other font you have in your system?

Comment: Note: In Debian Stretch, the Droid fonts have been deprecated.  With the recommended Noto fonts and with Emacs 25, the subscript n works as expected.